# Remove "Add to Cart" Button when Product Price is $0.00

Tags: price, addtocart, magento-2.2.5

I have looked through many similar questions, but many seem either far more convoluted than is necessary, or just doesn't make sense for my needs.

As the title states, I would like to remove the button if the product price is set to $0.00.  Or better yet, I'd like to have the button read "Coming Soon" instead of "Add to Cart" when the price is $0.00.

I figure this isn't too difficult for some of you seasoned veterans on here, but I honestly don't know where to start.

This will be implemented on Magento 2.2.5

Comment: Where you remove this button on listing or detail page ?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if question will not solve.

Comment: I'd like to remove it from both listing and detail page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove button in product details page, you need to override the **app/design/frontend/[themename]/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml** in your custom theme. Then, add below code :

```
<?php if ($_product->getPrice() > 0):?>
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
            <span class="add-cart btn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
        </button>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Override list.phtml [**For catalog category view**] file at

> app/design/frontend/`<themename>`/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

and apply this customization at line no 78

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->getPrice() > 0): ?>
    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
    <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $postParams['action'] ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <button type="submit"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                class="action tocart primary">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
        </button>
    </form>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="action tocart primary"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Coming Soon') ?></span></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

override the addtocart.phtml [For catalog product view] file at below path and add this code :

> app/design/frontend/`<themename>`/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
<?php  if ($_product->getPrice() > 0) : ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <button type="button"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Coming Soon')) ?>"
                    class="action tocart primary">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Coming Soon') ?></span>
            </button>
        <?php endif; ?>
```